# Mapbox in React Native does not show street with street name?

Tags: react-native, mapbox

I'm very new with rnmapbox (https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps). After following all steps settings up for iOS, my map only show country with borders and background color, how can I show the map with street and street name?

```
<MapboxGL.MapView
    styleURL={MapboxGL.StyleURL.Street}
    zoomLevel={zoomLevel}
    centerCoordinate={centerCoordinate}
    showUserLocation={true}
    style={styles.map}
>
    <MapboxGL.Camera
        zoomLevel={zoomLevel}
        centerCoordinate={centerCoordinate}
    />
    <MapboxGL.UserLocation />
</MapboxGL.MapView>
```

[image: ios-simulator]

Comment: My using library: https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps

Comment: kindly check this link https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/issues/2049#issuecomment-1186991861

Comment: @AbdulAzeem thanks for quick response. Yeah you are right! Need extra step for latest version `MapboxGL.setWellKnownTileServer(MapboxGL.TileServers.Mapbox);`